# Mysql inserting two records due to PHP mailer and my frontend is android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, insert, phpmailer

I am developing an android application. Basically, my application runs captcha first before calling the PHP file 'register.php' then the PHP file will insert it in the database. After registration, the query below will insert a record. When I add phpMailer to send a verification email, the record is inserted twice.

**register.php**

```
<?php
//Tutorial: http://www.androiddeft.com/login-registration-android-php-mysql/#Source_code_and_APK_Files

$response = array();
include 'db/db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

//Enable SMTP debugging. 
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;                               
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();      

//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = "mygmailaccount@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "my gmail password";                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                           
//Set TCP port to connect to 
$mail->Port = 465;

//Get the input request parameters
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

$mail->From = "example@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "RoadTrip";

$mail->addAddress($emailAddress, "Carl Baldemor");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "RoadTrip Account Verification";
$mail->Body = "<i>Please click the link below to verify your account</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "Insert Link here";    
$sent = $mail->send();

//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['password']) && isset($input['emailAddress']) && isset($input['firstName']) && isset($input['middleName']) && isset($input['lastName']) && isset($input['mobileNumber']) && isset($input['phoneNumber'])){

    $username = $input['username'];
    $passwordHash = $input['password'];
    $emailAddress = $input['emailAddress'];
    $firstName = $input['firstName'];
    $middleName = $input['middleName'];
    $lastName = $input['lastName'];
    $mobileNumber = $input['mobileNumber'];
    $phoneNumber = $input['phoneNumber'];
    $userTypeID = $input['userTypeID'];                         

    //Check if user already exist
    if(!userExists($username)){
        //Nest IF - Check if email exists
        if (!emailExists($emailAddress)){
                $sent();

                //Get a unique Salt
                $salt = getSalt();

                //Generate a unique password Hash
                $password = password_hash(concatPasswordWithSalt($passwordHash,$salt),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO user(userTypeID,firstName, middleName, lastName, emailAddress, mobileNumber, phoneNumber, username, password, salt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
                $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss",$userTypeID,$firstName,$middleName,$lastName,$emailAddress,$mobileNumber,$phoneNumber,$username,$password,$salt);
                $stmt->execute();
                $response["status"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "User created";
                $stmt->close();
                }

        } else{
            $response["status"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Email Exists";
        }
    }
    else{
        $response["status"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "User exists";
    }
}
else{
    $response["status"] = 3;
    $response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**register user function in android**

```
private void registerUser() {
        displayLoader();
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try {
            //Populate the request parameters
            request.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            request.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            request.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, firstName);
            request.put(KEY_MIDDLE_NAME, middleName);
            request.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, lastName);
            request.put(KEY_EMAIL_ADDRESS, emailAddress);
            request.put(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, mobileNumber);
            request.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
            request.put(KEY_USER_TYPE, userTypeID);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, register_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            //Check if user got registered successfully
                            if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                                //Set the user session
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                session.loginUser(username,firstName,lastName);
                                loadDashboard();
                            }else if(response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 1){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //Display error message if username is already existsing
                                etEmailAddress.setError("Email Address is already taken!");
                                etEmailAddress.requestFocus();
                            }else if(response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 2){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //Display error message if username is already existsing
                                etUsername.setError("Username is already taken!");
                                etUsername.requestFocus();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                        //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
    }
```

Comment: What debugging have you already done?  Are you sure that you want to be doing `$sent();`?

Comment: @PatrickQ I tried just using $mail->send(); function but sometimes there is an error on JSON object. I'm really now sure why it inserts two records but there is only one '$sent()' or one '$mail->send();'

Answer (score 1):

`$mail->send();` actually sends the mail and puts the result (a boolean) in `$sent`, so `$sent()` makes no sense, and does nothing (it will probably trigger a runtime error).

PHPMailer has nothing to do with your database; it's the logic you've wrapped it in that will be at fault. Your code only contains a single instance of a database insert call, and there are no loops or repeated calls, so it's likely that you are receiving multiple requests from your app; doing some logging or adding a random number to your subject line will reveal that.

You don't need to make your own salts with `password_hash`; it does it for you and embeds the salt in the hashed value, so you can replace:

```
//Get a unique Salt
$salt = getSalt();
//Generate a unique password Hash
$password = password_hash(concatPasswordWithSalt($passwordHash,$salt),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

with:

```
$password = password_hash($passwordHash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

without losing any security - in fact it's probably *more* secure. It's very confusing to call your plain-text password `$passwordHash` and the hashed password `$password`!